# Closed-form formula for system of two bivariate quadratic polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations

Given a system of two bivariate quadratic polynomials:

\begin{eqnarray}
a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 y + a_3 xy+a_4 x^2 + a_5 y^2 &= 0 \\
b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 y + b_3 xy+b_4 x^2 + b_5 y^2 &= 0
\end{eqnarray}

is there a closed-form formula for finding all of its roots?

I'm asking becase according to [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem) there are 4 solutions and there is a closed-form formula for [quartic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: Here's an ugly solution: Solve both equations for $y$ in terms of $x$. Then equate the solutions of these. You should get a quartic in $x$ after eliminating radicals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. To reduce it to one equation in one unknown, the command for [Walpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Ba0%20%2B%20a1%20x%20%2B%20a2%20y%20%2B%20a3%20x%20y%20%2B%20a4%20x%5E2%20%2B%20a5%20y%5E2,b0%20%2B%20b1%20x%20%2B%20b2%20y%20%2B%20b3%20x%20y%20%2B%20b4%20x%5E2%20%2B%20b5%20y%5E2,y%5D) is

> Resultant[a0 + a1 x + a2 y + a3 x y + a4 x^2 + a5 y^2, b0 + b1 x + b2 y + b3 x y + b4 x^2 + b5 y^2, y]

which eliminates $y$ and will give you a quartic solely in $x$,

$$P_4x^4+P_3x^3+P_2x^2+P_1x+P_0=0\tag1$$

where the $P_i$ are in the $a_i$ and $b_i$. Of course, with symbolic coefficients, it is pretty ugly.

**P.S.** There is a *maximum* of four solutions but if your $a_i$ and $b_i$ obey certain constraints such that $P_4=0$, you will end up with a cubic. Or, if $P_4=P_3=0$, then even a quadratic in $x$. For ex. if, $$a_5=\frac{-a_4b_3^2+2a_3b_3b_4}{4b_4^2}$$ $$b_5=\frac{b_3^2}{4b_4}$$

then this constraint causes $P_4=0$ and $(1)$ is just a cubic.

Comment: "obey certain constraints" - do you happen to know more details about it?

Comment: @EcirHana: I've edited and given an example.