# Is it possible to find intersection points of two ellipses analytically?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, systems-of-equations, conic-sections, elliptic-equations

We have two ellipses: first has semi-major and semi-minor axes parallel to coordinate axes with center at the coordinates origin, the second has random rotation and random center position. Is it possible to find intersection points (if exist) without numerical integration?

I tried to solve the system of two equations in Cartesian coordinates but the second equation has a sin and cos functions and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The $\sin$ and $\cos$ in the second equation will just be constants, so they aren't an issue. The actual issue is that the problem is more or less tantamount to solving a generic quartic. There are Cardano-like formulas for solving a quartic, with Cardano-like complications.

Comment: please edit your question to show the exact two equations that you are trying to simultaneously solve.

Comment: I agree with @SaucyO'Path ... Simultaneous solution of two polynomial equations of degree two in two unknowns reduces (in general) to solution of one polynomial equation in one variable of degree four.  See "resultant" and "Göbner basis".

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But using fourth-degree equation formula is often more cumbersome than numerically solving the equation.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I will not solve it by head, I will use the PC :) I just need a formulas to make a program for calculations.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I'm an idiot :) You are right

Comment: You need a solver for the a trigonometric equation that is of the form $ a \cos t + b \sin t + c \cos 2 t + d \sin 2 t + e = 0 $, and the solution of this equation requires the solution of a polynomial of degree $4$ (a quartic polynomial) in the variable $z = \tan \dfrac{t}{2} $

Comment: Closed form solution of quartic polynomials roots are available, so all the solutions of the trigonometric equation mentioned in the previous comment can be found, and hence, all the points of intersection can be found, without the need for any iterative numerical method.

Comment: In addition to the above, it is possible to find all the intersection points between any two conics (not just two ellipses), using an algebraic method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254314/solving-a-quadratic-equation-problem-with-two-variables/4255864#4255864)

Comment: You could write ellipse equations in following form: $a_1 x^2+b_1 x y+c_1 y^2+d_1 x+e_1 y +f_1=0$, $a_2 x^2+b_2 x y+c_2 y^2+d_2 x+e_2 y +f_2=0$. This can be solved analytically but the final formula is too large to write on the page.

Comment: Exact formulas in this case are "smoke and mirrors". Use a numerical method like 2D Newton-Raphson method...